# System.Net.Http.Formatting assembly changes automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

[image]

I have set my assembly reference as shown above to the my Web Api project. After compiling, it shows correct dll on the webapi's bin folder. But when I ran the app, it automatically changes to the older dll (ver 4.0). This is happening only for the bin folder's assembly. The web api's reference still shows the correct version (5.2.3). This is really strange. Could you tell me how to sort out this issue ? Thanks in advance.

It returns this error due to auto changed the assembly :

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting' or one of its  dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Your screenshot says "Specific Version = false", is your reference to "System.Net.Http.Formatting" or "System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3...." ??

Comment: @Dietz I need to reference V = 5.2.3.But even though I referred it properly where it changes automatically when I run the app.But it changes only the Bin folder's dll. The above Ui's reference will not change.It shows correctly as V 5.2.3.But Bin has been changed into V 4.0. Strange no ?

Comment: You could activate fusionlog and take a look at how .net finds the dll. That should shine a little light on the behaviour. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx